# WinXP RDC connection bar appears like the RDC connection bar for Windows Server 2008?

Tags: rdc

I have noticed that all of a sudden my RDC Connection Bar and the RDC Console (mstsc dialog) are appearing like their equivalent UI of Windows Server 2008.

I am on Win XP and here is what I see when I run the mstsc command:
[image: mstsc dialog in xp]

The connection bar that should appear like below is appearing like the one in Windows Server 2008[image]

When I connect to a remote server, I see the Server 2008 connection bar which is all blue and stylish:

[image]

Any clues, why I got bumped up to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your RDS/Terminal Server client is updated to 6.1 (I think) or above, it shows up like the 2008 one, nomatter what.

It's far more functional than the one you've screenshotted, in that you can move it around so that it doesn't sit ontop of the other menu bars, making you window session after session to get back to the original menu.

Comment: Mark, thanks for your answer. This seriously has creeped me out for a while now.

Comment: I think it's RDC 7 if I remember correctly. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969084